# App crashed after adding flutter firebase auth ui

Tags: flutter, firebaseui, flutter-dependencies

Flutter firebase auth UI have some issue, because of firebase_auth version miss match issue

My flutter app crashed and unable to identify an issue, after opening in an android studio, I got the issue and it is here

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.mycom.mypetshop. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.<init>(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:54)
        at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.registerWith(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:47)
        at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:20)
        at com.vyapari2online.mypetshop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
```

How to solve this?

> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency
>   depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0. 1]", but isn't
>   being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will
>   be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1
>   -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
>   15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the
>   issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_auth' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@16.0.2
>   -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_core' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends on project 'cloud_firestore' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@17.1.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends on project 'google_sign_in' which depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@16.0.1
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.

#flutter_firebase_ui have a lot of issues #google please hire me, I can help your developers

Comment: How are you getting on with the below, Midhilaj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dependency Configuration

For the gradle issue, make sure your Android SDK and Firebase/Firestore plugins are compatible versions are compatible. Here's what worked for me:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
}
```

In the module/app `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.timeswap.timeswapcore"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

...
}
```

Specifically, pay attention to the `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and the version numbers of `google-services` and `firebase_auth`. Fiddling with those numbers eventually led me to this config, and it may help you find your appropriate config.

## Firebase or Firestore Initialization

As for the App initialization, I have this

```
Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
```

in my `_initFirestore`, which is called right after `super.initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initFirestore();
    checkCurrentUser();
}
```

Firebase (and all other Firebase plugins that I've used) is initialized similarly, but with the `firebase_core:` dependency instead of `cloud_firestore:` in `pubspec.yaml`.

For instance, from the `flutter/plugins/packages/firebase_storage` GitHub [repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/example/lib/main.dart):

```
void main() async {
  final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'test',
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: Platform.isIOS
          ? '1:159623150305:ios:4a213ef3dbd8997b'
          : '1:159623150305:android:ef48439a0cc0263d',
      gcmSenderID: '159623150305',
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyChk3KEG7QYrs4kQPLP1tjJNxBTbfCAdgg',
      projectID: 'flutter-firebase-plugins',
    ),
  );
  final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(
      app: app, storageBucket: 'gs://flutter-firebase-plugins.appspot.com');
  runApp(MyApp(storage: storage));
}
```

You can also use [this Medium post](https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-ui-with-flutter-ccd6d4d6807) as a guide to get started with the flutter Firebase Auth UI.

For future reference, you can navigate to `flutter/plugins/packages/{package name}` on Github and find `main.dart` inside of `examples/lib` for a demo. Feel free to leverage this to solve your dependency issue as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `FirebaseApp` before using it. You can add it to your `onCreate` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
}
```

Also make sure you have the dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ....
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue and solved by adding Facebook app id in AndroidManifest.xml
Try run Android app with Android studio you will get the error message